# How can I come up with meaningful (and exciting) scenes for my character's journey?

Tags: creative-writing

I am struggling to find conflict in each place (countries for my story) I'm working on. I have some fun ones (small but whack adventures that my character partakes) but I don't have an intriguing conflict for each of the countries. My characters undergo little personal adventures, but I don't think it will hold up a 500 page book. I don't know how to figure out adventures that are super intriguing, fun, and not fillers that add no value to the story (but adventures that add to their personal stories).

What can I do?

Comment: Elaborate more on the story.  Is this a tale of youngsters growing up?  Adults going on a trip between college and a job?  etc.  It will matter.

Comment: Can you find a buddy to re-phrase at least the English version? 

Is this merely a 'journey'? Is it a 'road trip'? Can it qualify as a 'quest'?

Where is the need for conflict written?

Making each 'place' a country might be the best tactic ever… and how does it come into your story?

Why is 'fun' or 'whacky' less useful?

When your characters undergo 'little' adventures, d'you mean 'few' or that however many, the adventures are of slight consequence?

Why should any book need 500 pages? Have you not read many shorter tomes?

If not adventures, what else could you use?

Comment: Would you mind telling us which three or four writers you most and least admire?

Can you also tell us both your age and where you're from?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/ might give you some ideas for conflict in various areas of traveling.

Answer (score 1):

The small adventures should follow naturally from the interaction of your main story arch, the characters, and the setting.

For example, if you are telling a spy thriller and your protagonist and antagonist are a spy and the agent that hunts him and they come through France, it is clear that one of the "small adventures" will involve the spy evading the counter agent in a typical French situation. That's how you get all those car chases through the streets of Paris or James Bond escaping his pursuers by skiing down the slopes of the Swiss Alps.

So begin by working out the main plot, develop the characters, and research the settings. In my experience the "small adventures" will present themselves without further effort.

---

A great how-to-write book that shows in eye-opening detail how a story can be derived mainly from its setting, is *Mastering the Process* by Elizabeth George. George writes mystery novels and has a very idiosyncratic approach to how she develops her stories. In *Mastering the Process* she shows step by step how she came up with the story for her novel *Careless in Red* by exploring the story's location. You may find her ideas instructive.

Answer (score 1):

Your main source of conflict will be the antagonist(s).

Here are some tips:

- You can have one or several antagonists (for a 500-page book, you might even want to look into a system of antagonists, like the peals of an onion or something similar... levels in a platform game?)
- Your antagonists should have one or several plans (e.g. a master plan and sub plans/master-plan-step-plans). This could make your story work by just having the protagonist trying to prevent these steps and ultimately the master plan.
- One of my favorites are, the antagonists try to save the/their world... they're just using godawful methods (murder, ethnic cleansing, deportations, black magic, you name it...) But their motive is to save the/their world, and they are convinced their method is the only way...
- This is so much better if the world really is in peril.
- If you have antagonists with well-designed plans, you'll get all the conflict you really need. And, of course, once your character starts interfering with these plans, the antagonists will start hunting them for real and making new plans involving your character (and his demise).

You speak of countries, so there are sources for conflict there as well:

- Wars
- Famine, drought, epidemics
- Economic crisis
- Politic crisis, coups, scandals

Relate this to your antagonists that may only try to deal with these problems or may even have caused them as tools in their plans.

Other conflicts could come from more mundane elements, such as your main character's [arc](https://www.helpingwritersbecomeauthors.com/write-character-arcs/) (development/evolution), if they have one.

And finally, to order all these conflicts, look into your [story structure](https://www.helpingwritersbecomeauthors.com/secrets-story-structure-complete-series/). This will also help you create a cohesive story that will likely link the conflicts into a larger whole (and inform you on what conflicts you'll want and when, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Treat it similarly to if you were trying to find conflict for a character - what does that country want and how can you stop them from getting it. Depending on how many countries there are and how differently their systems, laws, trades, etc are, you will have a list of different wants that could contradict and cause conflict amongst other countries.

For example:

1. Country A wants to contain their trade within their own country and with no other.
2. Country B wants to exapand their wealth and economy.
3. Country C wants to establish a new ruler and overthrow the current monarch.
4. Country D wants to ensure peace among their nation.

With these single lines I can now create conflict by saying:

1. Country A doesn't get what they want because B is threatening invasion if they don't start trading.
2. Country B doesn't immediately gain wealth because the other countries all stop trading due to B's authoritarian approach.
3. Country C doesn't get what they want because the monarch in question is actually a badass who apparently can't be killed.
4. Country D doesn't get what they want because they have to align their forces with C in order to stop B.

It's really simple. They don't all have to entertwine (C's problem is due to an unknown character) but by creating wishes, you can simply add barriers that prevent them. You don't have to add great detail to each and every one of the countries desires but by expanding your own knowledge on the wants and woes of each nation, you can pick and choose which conflict to add into your story!

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your answer and examples, @BubbleQueen! However, it is my fault that wasn't very clear (My apologies!). My story is a contemporary novel, my protagonist is going around the world for life meaning, and the story doesn't necessarily have an antagonist. I don't know if this clears any confusion, but could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The arc of your story turns on their growing knowledge of themselves.

Therefore, first of all you must decide what you want them to learn.

Then you need to consider what adventures will first exemplify what they lack (even to themselves), then push them to overcome that, and finally demonstrate that they have gained it.